# Egg problem-Brain Teaser-Amazon Interview Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

A lady from the chicken farm gathers the eggs and brings it to sell it in the market.

She sells the eggs but few eggs are left over.

The 2nd day the left over eggs was doubled.

Yet she sells the same amount of eggs as the 1st day.

The 3rd day the left over eggs was tripled.

Yet she sells the same amount of eggs as the 1st day.

The 4th day the left over eggs was quadrupled.

Yet she sells the same amount of eggs as the 1st day.

The 5th day the left over eggs was quintupled.

Yet she sells the same amount of eggs as the 1st day. And the remaining eggs where disposed


**Question**
How many eggs did she take to the market on the 1st day and how many was left over?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to M.SE. What have you tried and what's giving you trouble? Please share your thoughts on the problem so that people may give help that's actually relevant to you.

Comment: This was an Amazon interview question and this was exactly asked.. i was left blank for this ;/

Comment: As an interview question, they don't really guarantee a unique answer.  Just coming up with the expression for the number of eggs left (or even the process to find it) is probably sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  Let $x$ be the original number of eggs and $y$ be the number sold each day.  After the doubling on the second day she has $2(x-y)$ eggs.  After the tripling on the third day she has $3(2(x-y)-y)$ eggs.  Keep going.  Usually in problems like this you are given that the process comes out even on the last day.  Otherwise you don't have enough information to solve the problem.  In this case, for a given $y$, we can always increase $x$ by $1$ and the remainder by $120$ (why that?) and have another solution.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few potential answers here but ill just try one option. 
*Lets say a few = 3
*Each day she throws out the left over eggs
*She takes an increasing number of eggs to market every day because she has a few superstar chickens that lay more than the others :)
day 1 she takes 103 eggs to market, sells 100 and throws out 3
day 2 she takes 106 eggs to market, sells 100 and throws out 6
day 3 she takes 109 eggs to market, sells 100 and throws out 9
day 4 she takes 112 eggs to market, sells 100 and throws out 12
day 4 she takes 115 eggs to market, sells 100 and throws out 15
answer = 103